# format date in listview control

Tags: asp.net

the date  is like this :12/07/2009  7:30:45 PM

now i need  to  format the date like this

**Nov 11, 2009 7:30AM** 
how can i achive this  one
 thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
Eval("CreatedDate", "{0:MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm tt}")
```

Taken from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: You should use one 'h' for hours, else it would be 'Nov 11, 2009 07:30AM'.