# datatype Date also showing time in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I have MySQL Database in which there is column with it's data type is date. All working fine but when I fetch information from that column it shows date as well as time. I don't want to show time there. In MySQL table I see only a date but when I populate the table through a `listview` that column also shows time. I am using ASP.net in which I have used `Listview` to populate my table.

> e.g. 2016/11/10 12:00:00PM

Comment: What is the data type you're using in .NET?  If it's `DateTime` then, well, that has a time component.  How are you displaying it on the page?  Can't you just format the output the way you want to display it?  What does that have to do with the backing database?

Comment: You should be able to format the date however you want in the Listview.  Something like this: `Eval("MyDateColumn", "{0:MMM dd, yyyy}")`

Comment: @David It is just an simple label in which I am getting values from data table

Comment: @SUN: The default string representation of a `DateTime` is going to include the time component.  Use a format string to customize how you want to display it.

Comment: Already voted to close the question, but this is also a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928412/format-date-in-listview-control

Comment: @RickS Thank you for your help. Worked for me